# Java Inheritance within the same package not finding class

Tags: java, inheritance, package

I have two classes within the same folder and package. The location of them is code/src/enemy. These are the two classes:

```
package src.enemy;

public class Enemy{
  String name = "";
  float maxHealth = 100;
  float health;
  public Enemy(String name) // This made me laugh more than it should
  {
    this.name = name;
    this.health = this.maxHealth;
  }
}
```

and

```
package src.enemy;

public class baseEnemy extends Enemy{
public baseEnemy(String name)
{
   super(name);
}
```

}

For some reason when I try to compile them I get:

```
:3: error: cannot find symbol
public class baseEnemy extends Enemy{
 symbol: class Enemy
```

I'm Compiling with Javac. I'm not really sure why baseEnemy can't inherit enemy when they are in the same folder and package.

Comment: Can you write how you use javac to compile them ? The exact line from which folder.

Comment: javac ~/Documents/Assignments/Ass4/Code/src/enemy/Enemy.java. And this compiled fine. Then javac ~/Documents/Assignments/Ass4/Code/src/enemy/baseEnemy.java which threw the error.

Comment: I haven't used javac directly, but I think that you must give both files to javac. Eg javac path/to/A path/to/C

Comment: When i do this i get a different error. Ive changed the baseEnemy class to have a constructor with parameter name and calling super(name). The error i get now is :   constructor Enemy in class Enemy cannot be applied to given types;
public class baseEnemy extends Enemy{
       ^
  required: String
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: Using your current code, and specifying both files on the command line, I am able to compile with no errors.

Comment: I've moved your answer to an answer post, and trimmed out an unfortunate choice of words. Please [read this when you get a moment](http://www.r-word.org/r-word-why-pledge.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
javac ~/Documents/Assignments/Ass4/Code/src/enemy/Enemy.java.
```

No. You should be in `~/Documents/Assignments/Ass4/Code`, and issue

```
javac src/enemy/Enemy.java
```

and similarly for the other class.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have no constructor in your baseEnemy Class. If you change it to:

public class Enemy {

```
String name = "";
float maxHealth = 100;
float health;
public Enemy(String name) // This made me laugh more than it should
{
    this.name = name;
    this.health = this.maxHealth;
}

public Enemy() {
}
}
```

and then

```
public class baseEnemy extends Enemy {

public baseEnemy(String name) {
    super(name);
}
}
```

it'll be able to feed the name. Ideally level 0 Classes should always have a 0 argument constructor :). Hope that helps.

Comment: You are right, but I think the compiler gives another message for this error.

Comment: I've compiled and built it at my end using the edited script above have you tried a clean & build?

Comment: I'm not using an IDE. I might try and delete everything and try again

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*.

So initially I made the directory and "Code" had a capital c. I Then saw this and made a new folder with a small c. What I didn't realise was that my atom code was referencing the one in the folder with a capital C.